# Split time not containing seconds from datetime in R

Tags: r

How can I split "`16/03/2021 08:32`" into time only with R?

I tried using "`format(as.POSIXct(bike_rides1$started_at), format = "%H:%M")`" and it returned 00:00, I also tried "`format(as.POSIXct(bike_rides1$started_at), format = "%H:%M:%S")`" and it returned 00:00:00 as well.

Comment: The date part of your string is in a non standard format.  See this for a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261872/convert-date-string-in-format-mon-day-year-time-am-pm-to-posixlt-format-in-r

Comment: `substr("16/03/2021 08:32", 12, 16)`?

Comment: `sub("^\\S+\\s+", '', "16/03/2021 08:32")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate::dmy_hm()` (day-month-year hour-minutes) to get your dates into a standard format, and then your format would work:

```r
lubridate::dmy_hm("16/03/2021 08:32") |>
  format(format = "%H:%M")

#> [1] "08:32"
```